# how to manage and send notifications to multiple devices a user is logged in?

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm developing an application having a Mobile App and a Web Panel, on which a user can log in on multiple devices at the same time. I'm using Firebase Cloud Messaging to send notifications.

So currently to send notifications I'm storing the Firebase Cloud Messaging token in an array and sending notifications by looping through that array e.g users can open the same account on 2 browsers/laptops + log in to 3 different mobile devices with the same account, so 5 different tokens will be stored in the database. Every time a user opens a mobile app it gets a new token which is saved in the DB. I'm not removing any token at any time.

So there will be a bulk of tokens collecting in my DB, which will take more and more time in sending notifications to a specific user on all the tokens.

So I want to know how can I manage these tokens? how can I validate? because I'm not removing tokens, notification sending requests always return 200. Should I use topic instead of tokens but how will I unsubscribe a user from the server-side.

Comment: Sounds like a fine design. Do you actually have a coding question though?

Comment: design is not fine. tokens length will never decrease, I can go up to 1000/user in a month which will also increase the notification sending time.

Answer (score 0):

You could create multiple attributes (instead of a string array) in the database (tokenFromAndroid, tokenFromIos, tokenFromWeb, etc.. other platforms). Every time you call the Firebase SDK to generate the token you could update the respective attribute in the database so the token is always the newest for that platform. In this case you would not have too many tokens for one user.

Comment: but suppose if a user login the same account from 2 different android devices. Only the latest logged-in device will get a notification. I want to send the notification to both android devices.

Answer (score 0):

in my opinion you have to  use Firebase with NODEJS or Laravel
and add a **Device table** which contains all devices that user logged in from.

like this:

- user_id.
- device_id  (serial number).
- device name .
- firebase_token.
- state( logged in/out).

so when you need to push to specific user you have to go to device table and send to the used device's token.

so user can still receive a notification in all used  devices